# How do I set the PyQGIS environnement on Windows properly?

Tags: python, import, module, cmd, qgis

I'm having problems with a specific error, which is pretty common from what I can see but can't seem to find a solution.

When I try to import the qgis module the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: No module named 'qgis'
```

So far this is the [guide](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/3/) I'm using and here's the settings for the .cmd, I'm assuming it has something to do with this:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\bin\pycharm.exe;%PATH%
cd %HOMEPATH%\TER\development
start "PyCharm aware of Quantum GIS" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\bin\pycharm.exe" %*
```

EDIT: After applying luca76's suggestion

```
C:\Python34\python.exe D:/TER/development/test.py
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "D:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Process finished with exit code 3

I'm assuming that it has to do something with using calling Python 3.4 and not Python 2.7.

EDIT: Round 3

My attempt this time included a slightly modified version of Lucas proposal.

What I did was to remove the HOMEPATH however this time when I try to import the qgis module I get a traceback:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qgis.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
  File "D:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 3, in <module
>
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put environment variables before the execution of o4w_env.bat: (**rembember to fix ALL directory paths**!)

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\bin\pycharm.exe;%PATH%
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;%PATH%

call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat

cd %HOMEPATH%\TER\development
start "PyCharm aware of Quantum GIS" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.6\bin\pycharm.exe" %*
```

Comment: Thank you @luca76, it loaded the PyCharm just fine but it didn't solved the problem, or it did but another one just came up.

Comment: I've tried another solution found here [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102). Everything works fine, at least that's what I believe, until the very last step when I run the python script. I get the same error import as in the initial state.

Comment: Apparently, too many Python installations plus the ArcGIS Python dependent makes things very complicated. This is why I'm probably going to work on Linux for my plugin, it seems as if it's an insurmountable problem.

Comment: Could you try my modified script in the same answer? I've modified the order of environment variables

Comment: It won't even load PyCharm. Anyhow, thanks for the effort @luca76. I'm having problems on Linux as well, this time with compiling the file.